# Virtual method with variations for different types

Tags: c++, c++17, template, strategy-pattern

Each animal type will call `reactToOwner()` and exhibit its own behaviour.  So simply define a `reactToOwner()` override for each
animal type, right?  But in this case `reactToOwner()` has many common parts for each animal type, e.g. `lookAtOwner()`, `doNothing()`, `goAboutOwnBusiness()`.
So simply define hook methods between them and define their own overrides in each animal type, right?  Yes, but some such hook methods will not apply
to some animal types (e.g. a `Cow` will not call `jumpAndDown()`).  So the best I could think of is to use templates and check the template type
during compile time with `if constexpr`, which does not cost any inefficiency, though the dynamic casting does.  When adding new lines
to `Animal::doReactToOwner()` in the future, one can check what type needs what, and any new lines that will be used by all Animal types
can be added directly, whereas conventional `doReactToOwner()` overrides for each animal type (Strategy Pattern) may easily miss such lines that are to be shared with all animal types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Animal {
    template <typename T> void doReactToOwner() const;
    virtual void reactToOwner() const = 0;
    void lookAtOwner() const { std::cout << "Looks at owner.\n"; }
    void turnQuiet() const { std::cout << "Turns quiet.\n"; }
    void doNothing() const { }
    void goAboutOwnBusiness() const { std::cout << "Does its own thing.\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct AnimalCRTP : Animal {
    virtual void reactToOwner() const override { doReactToOwner<T>(); }
    void jumpsUpAndDown() const { std::cout << "Jumps up and down.\n"; }
};

struct Dog : AnimalCRTP<Dog> {
    void barks() const { std::cout << "Barks.\n"; }
};

struct Cat : AnimalCRTP<Cat> {
    void meows() const { std::cout << "Meows.\n"; }
};

struct Cow : AnimalCRTP<Cow> {
    void moos() const { std::cout << "Moos.\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
void Animal::doReactToOwner() const {
    lookAtOwner();
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Dog>)
        dynamic_cast<const Dog*>(this)->barks();
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Dog> || std::is_same_v<T, Cat>)
        dynamic_cast<const T*>(this)->jumpsUpAndDown();
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Cat> || std::is_same_v<T, Cow>)
        turnQuiet();
    doNothing();
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Cat>)
        dynamic_cast<const Cat*>(this)->meows();
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Cow>)
        dynamic_cast<const Cow*>(this)->moos();
    goAboutOwnBusiness();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Dog reacts:\n";
    Dog dog;
    dog.reactToOwner();
    std::cout << "\nCat reacts:\n";
    Cat cat;
    cat.reactToOwner();
    std::cout << "\nCow reacts:\n";
    Cow cow;
    cow.reactToOwner();
}
```

Output :

```
Dog reacts:
Looks at owner.
Barks.
Jumps up and down.
Does its own thing.

Cat reacts:
Looks at owner.
Jumps up and down.
Turns quiet.
Meows.
Does its own thing.

Cow reacts:
Looks at owner.
Turns quiet.
Moos.
Does its own thing.
```

Answer (score 2):

Captain Hatteras has a nice answer, I just want to present another way of doing it that does not use CRTP at all, but does address your remark that:

> [...] conventional doReactToOwner() overrides for each animal type (Strategy Pattern) may easily miss such lines that are to be shared with all animal types.

The solution to this would be to have a non-virtual `reactToOwner()` in the base class that has all the behavior that is shared with all animals, but which calls further virtual functions that do only the animal-specific things. For example:

```
struct Animal {
    void reactToOwner() const;
protected:
    virtual void initialReactToOwner() const = 0;
    virtual void finalReactToOwner() const = 0;
    void lookAtOwner() const { std::cout << "Looks at owner.\n"; }
    void jumpsUpAndDown() const { std::cout << "Jumps up and down.\n"; }
    void turnQuiet() const { std::cout << "Turns quiet.\n"; }
    void doNothing() const { }
    void goAboutOwnBusiness() const { std::cout << "Does its own thing.\n"; }
};

struct Cat: public Animal {
private:
    void initialReactToOwner() const final;
    void finalReactToOwner() const final;
    void meows() const { std::cout << "Meows.\n"; }
};

void Animal::reactToOwner() const {
    lookAtOwner();
    initialReactToOwner();
    doNothing();
    finalReactToOwner();
    goAboutOwnBusiness();
}

void Cat::initialReactToOwner() const {
    jumpsUpAndDown();
    turnQuiet();
}

void Cat::finalReactToOwner() const {
    meows();
}
```

P.S.: [cows *do* jump](https://www.google.com/search?q=jumping%20cows).

Answer (score 1):

Small things:

- When `dynamic_cast` is used on a pointer and fails, it returns `nullptr`. In this case, it can't fail because you check the type beforehand, so use `static_cast` (if you keep your current design).
- `Animal`'s destructor should be virtual.

In this example, you don't really need polymorphism. You could just use CRTP without loss.

Instead of having the AnimalCRTP's `doReactToOwner`, you could put common functionality into structs and implement doReactToOwner in every animal. This would allow users to make their own animals.

Here is one way of implementing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct AnimalCRTP {
    void reactToOwner() const {
        static_cast<const T*>(this)->reactToOwner();
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct TameAnimal : public AnimalCRTP<T>{
    void goAboutOwnBusiness() const { std::cout << "Does its own thing.\n"; }
    void lookAtOwner() const { std::cout << "Looks at owner.\n"; }
};

// Might want to shorten the name... 

struct DogCatCommonFunctionality{
    void jumpUpAndDown() const{ std::cout << "Jumps up and down.\n"; }
};

struct CowCatCommonFunctionality{
    void turnQuiet() const { std::cout << "Turns quiet.\n"; }
};

struct Dog : public TameAnimal<Dog>,
             public DogCatCommonFunctionality
{
    void barks() const { std::cout << "Barks.\n"; }
    void reactToOwner() const{
        lookAtOwner();
        barks();
        jumpUpAndDown();
        goAboutOwnBusiness();
    }
};

struct Cat : public TameAnimal<Cat>, 
             public DogCatCommonFunctionality,
             public CowCatCommonFunctionality
{
    void meows() const { std::cout << "Meows.\n"; }
    void reactToOwner() const{
        lookAtOwner();
        jumpUpAndDown();
        turnQuiet();
        meows();
        goAboutOwnBusiness();
    }
};

struct Cow : public TameAnimal<Cow>, 
             public CowCatCommonFunctionality{
    void moos() const { std::cout << "Moos.\n"; }
    void reactToOwner() const{
        lookAtOwner();
        turnQuiet();
        moos();
        goAboutOwnBusiness();
    }
};
```